# Why can't scons find my project's source files?

Tags: c++, scons

Here's [my project](https://github.com/seanochoa/IeiuniumTela/tree/develop) on github.

Here's my SConstruct file:

```
SConscript('main.scons', variant_dir = 'build', duplicate = 0)
```

Here's my main.scons file:

```
import sys
import os
import fnmatch

def find_source_files(directory, ext = "cpp"):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.' + ext):
          matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for f in find_source_files('src'):
        print f
else: 
    Program(target = 'main.bin', source = find_source_files('src'))
```

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
bitcycle @ cypher ~/git/IeiuniumTela $ find $(pwd) -name "*.bin" -or -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;;  scons; find $(pwd) -name "*.bin" -or -name "*.o"

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
gcc -o build/main.bin
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/main.bin] Error 4
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Here's what happens when I run `python main.scons' to test it:

```
bitcycle @ cypher ~/git/IeiuniumTela $ python main.scons
src/main.cpp
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why it can't find my source files.  Any suggestions or ideas here?

**[UPDATE]** After getting some good direction from the mailing list, I found that this worked "good enough" for me.

**/SConstruct**:  `SConscript('src/main.scons', variant_dir = 'build', duplicate = 0)`

**/src/main.scons**:  `Program(target = 'main.bin', source = Glob('*.cpp'))`

See the github repository for the full source tree.  I've also added an empty build directory to the repo for completeness.  I find it interesteding that:

a.  SCons' version of Glob isn't recursive, in the context of this build tool for discovering source.  I would expect that a recursive discovery option is preferred.  :(

b.  I *need* to put the scons file in the same directory as the source file (which is annoying).

c.  Print statements apparently work, but sys.stdout.write doesn't (from the python module).

Comment: I've got a question out the scons user mailing list, we'll see what that turns up.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your `main.scons` file is already in the `src` directory, and your `find_source_file` is actually searching `src/src`?
It found the source sources for me when I moved the scons files to the top directory.

**Update:**
Upon investigation, `variant_dir` sets the working directory to `build`, so your `find_source_files` looks for files in `build/src` and finds nothing. Would be probably better to either call `find_source_files` from the SConstruct file, or to use `VariantDir()` inside main.scons instead.

Comment: If `find_source_files` was failing, then executing it directly (via `python main.scons`) wouldn't print out the list of src files.  :(

Comment: Sorry about that, it actually didn't work for me neither. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SCons treats relative directory paths differently from Python, so I wouldnt be surprised to see a difference between the test execution and the SCons execution. Typically in SCons everything is relative to the root SConstruct script, or the SConscript script.

Your code appears correct, but how about adding some debugging print statements in `find_source_files()` to find out exactly what's happening?

Perhaps you plan to use the `find_source_files()` function more extensively later on, but for the simple case of one source file, it seems like you are over complicating things and you could just use the following in `main.scons`:

```
Program(target = 'main.bin', source = 'src/main.cpp')
```